# How can I jump to a sibling node in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin-treesitter

Say I want to write a custom function / keyboard shortcut to jump to the next sibling node in Neovim/Lua. In theory, I can get that with [`TSNode:next_sibling()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/treesitter.html#treesitter-node). But I'm lost as to how I would put the parts together here:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('NextSibling',
  function()
    // get node currently under cursor and/or visually selected
    // pass this to treesitter and get the next sibling
    // jump to the result  
    end,
    { nargs = 0 }
)
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ns', vim.cmd.NextSibling)
```

There is some guidance [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/rmgxkf/better_treesitter_way_to_jump_to_parentsibling/) but it's a little out-of-date -- looking for the current simplest way to achieve this.